# Count 2 columns Mysql

Tags: mysql

Count 2 columns

Here is my table

```
Table A
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          id          |        typec                NOM        |    
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|           1          |        Plat         |        A         |
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|           2          |    Steeple-chase    |        B         |
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|           3          |        Haies        |        C         |
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want the output to be:

```
+------------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|      nom   |  Plat  |Steeple-chase |  Haies  |   ALL     |
+------------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|      A     |   10   |      2       |    8    |    20     |
+------------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
|      B     |  100   |      50      |   50    |   100     |
+------------+--------+--------------+------+--------------+
|      C     |   5    |       5      |    5    |   15      |
+------------+--------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

Currently, I run this query but the result is not good

```
SELECT nom, typec, count(*) AS count
FROM p_mu.cachedate
GROUP BY nom, typec;
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: What does "not good" mean? Also, your question says "I want the output to be", followed by a table with 5 columns, none of which are named typec or count, and then you present a SQL that would return 3 columns, 2 of which was not in the table you wanted. Can you make sure you posted the right expected output? You also need to explain how you arrive at the output table, what is the relationship between the rows in the output table and your input table? How, for instance, did you arrive at the values 10,2,8,20 in the first row? Where do they come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for pivot/conditional aggregation (I would be be more certain if you published sample data that matched desired result)

```
SELECT nom, sum(case when typec ='plat' then 1 else 0 end) as 'plat', 
       sum(case when typec ='steeple_chase' then 1 else 0 end) as 'steeple-chase',
       sum(case when typec ='hais' then 1 else 0 end) as 'hais',
       count(*) AS 'all'
FROM p_mu.cachedate
GROUP BY nom;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been going around in circles since yesterday

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is not COUNT(), it is the + operator

```
SELECT nom, typec1, typec2, typec3, typec1+typec2+typec3 AS ALL
FROM p_mu.cachedate
GROUP BY nom
```

Try if that works and share the result!